# Adding a "close" button to Three20 TTWebController - iPhone

Tags: iphone, three20, modalviewcontroller

I am presenting a TTWebController as a Modal View using this code:

```
TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"*" toModalViewController:[TTWebController class]];
```

Everything works great, except that there is no "close" button on the TTWebController. I know this is usually pushed from the side and given a "back" button, but is there a way to add a "close" button without digging into the actual Three20 code?

**Update:**

Here is the code that I am using to create the text and then push the Modal View onto the screen. I want to dynamically send whichever URL is clicked, in place of "YourUrlHere".

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
TTStyledTextLabel* label = [[[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
NSString* labelText = @"http://www.yahoo.com http://www.google.com http://www.test.com";
label.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:labelText lineBreaks:NO URLs:YES];
[self.view addSubview:label];   

TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
myWebView *newViewController = [[myWebView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TTStyledTextLabelWebView" bundle:nil incomingURL:[NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.YourUrlHere.com"]];
[map from:@"*" toModalViewController:[newViewController class]];
```

Comment: That mapping looks wrong, do you really mean to use *?

Comment: yes... the link works and opens the modal view. The problem is the TTWebController doesn't have a "close" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you actually want is your own view controller, that either inherits from or contains a TTWebController.  Create and map to that instead of the raw `TTWebController`, put the button wherever you like and wire up the on touch up inside to `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`  That should do the trick.

EDIT:

So now you have a custom web view of type `myWebView` that I am assuming inherits from `TTWebController`.  That's good.  As an aside, you don't really need to initialize a new instance of it just to get the class, you can do that with just `[myWebView class]` because the class message is on the class, not the instance.

However, even though you have decided to create a new instance using a xib, I don't think TTNavigator will be instantiating your controller instance in that same way.  Instead I believe it will launch with this constructor (extracted from TTWebController.m)

```
- (id)initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query {
  if (self = [self init]) {
    NSURLRequest* request = [query objectForKey:@"request"];
    if (request) {
      [self openRequest:request];
    } else {
      [self openURL:URL];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
```

So, in your child implementation, you can provide a customized version of this implementation like so:

```
- (id)initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query {
  if (self = [super initWithNavigatorURL:URL query:query]) {
    // code that creates a button and puts it somewhere
  }
  return self;
}
```

I haven't tested it, I'd be interested in seeing what it actually is doing if it isn't doing that.  If you prefer xibs (like me, unlike three20) then you'll need to do an extra step of loading that.   I have a category in my utility framework that helps with this:

**NSBundle+LoadNibView.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSBundle(LoadNibView)

+ (id) loadNibView:(NSString*)className;

@end
```

**NSBundle+LoadNibView.m**

```
#import "NSBundle+LoadNibView.h"

@implementation NSBundle(LoadNibView)

+ (id) loadNibView:(NSString*)className
{
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

@end
```

The `objectAtIndex` part is because all xibs contain an array, even if there is only one view inside.  This will just return the first UIView in the xib.

Comment: But then how do I pass the tapped link information to the WebView? I was using TTWebController because there doesn't seem to be a way to extract the URL and pass it to a another view.

Comment: If I'm correct in understanding what you are doing, you've already setup the Navigator and the Map.  TTNavigator passes the information for you.

Comment: If you just want to extract the URL, I'm sure there are ways of doing that as well, but you'll need to post some more code

Comment: I added that to myWebView and it is receiving the URL. I've got other problems now ... thanks for your help.

Comment: glad to hear you got it worked out, I'm not a big fan of Three20 to be honest I feel like it's a cancer that keeps spreading all around my project, but it does have it's merits and I have used it for one or two small projects.